# Why does integer division truncation not occur here?

Tags: c, truncation, kernighan-and-ritchie

I was going through the examples in K&R, and stumbled upon this bit of code:

```
celcius=5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
```

The author says that we can't use 5/9 since integer division truncation will lead to a value of 0.

The program however, outputs 17 as answer when fahr=0. By my calculations, (0-32)/9 should lead to -3 (due to truncation) and then -3*5 = -15, and NOT -17. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(0 - 32) is first multiplied by 5, giving -160. -160 / 9 = -17.

Answer (score 3):

What the author say is that one should not use

`celsius = (fahr-32)*(5/9);`

---

As for your question,

`celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;`

is different from

`celsius = 5 * ((fahr-32) / 9);`

In the later case, you would indeed get `-15` when `fahr=0`.